# Is there a need to install CSS3 plug-ins?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on styling my web page on a separate CSS file. I have created a link on my HTML file to apply the styling effects to my web page but it doesn't show any effect.

I tried the most basic styles to see if there was an effect to my webpage but nothing happened. I tried writing the codes with Microsoft Visual Studio, and then Notepad++ but still, no effect occurred. I also tried opening my web page using the latest version of Mozilla Firefox, Internet explorer and Microsoft Edge to see any effect but nothing happened.

I tried styling my h1 element using the codes I'll show on the next field

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../css/staret.css" type="text.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1> Football lives </h1>
</body>

</html>
```

on my staret.css file, here's what I wrote:

```
h1 {
    color: Red;
}
```

I expected to see "Football lives" in red color but the actual output was the default color black.

Comment: I like using [repl.it](https://repl.it) Web Repls (HTML/CSS/JS language) to experiment with web pages. It removes all the confusion of actually implementing your CSS/JS files.

Comment: Make sure that your stylesheet file is where it's supossed to be. Could you post a screenshot of your files directory?

Comment: Is your css directory in the same directory as the html file? If so, then when linking to files you don't need the leading `../` in the `href`. This is telling the server to find a css file 1 level up the directory tree (which might not even exist). Your href should look like: `"css/staret.css"`

Comment: What's a CSS plugin?

Answer (score 2):

No need to install CSS plugin. There is a little error in your code while linking CSS with HTML.
It should be, type = "text/css" in place of "text.css"

Answer (score 1):

No. CSS3 is included. No need to think about it as an 'addon' or separate thing.

Your issues are with however you are authoring the file. Try putting it in a jsFiddle. : )

```css
.box {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ff0066;
  padding: 1rem;
  transform: rotate(20deg); /* CSS3 */
 }
```

```html
<section class='example'>
  <div class='box'>hi</div>
</section>
```